# Google fit rest api request

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

when I request on google fit rest api the steps count the only steps I see are the value user_input, and then the Google Fit App write on google fitness store or not?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Adding more detail and maybe an example of the code you have tried might help others answers answer this question.

Comment: Add some code snipshots?

Comment: Does this issue reproduce in the latest versions of Google Fit? If you still have the debugLog when the issue happened, would be great to share. Also please try replicating the issue quickstart apps. This could also help us pinpoint what's the real cause of your issue.